# ROS msg format specification

Tags: ros, print, rostopic-echo, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have created a custom CAN bus message but I would like to change the way that the information is printed out.

My .msg file is:

```
# Custom message for sending the IMU data to the hydraulic test system
# BJEM 19th May 2014.

Header header
uint32 time_ms
uint16 time_us
uint32 id         # 11/29 bit code
uint8 msgtype     # bits of MSGTYPE_*
uint8 len         # count of data bytes (0..8)
uint8[] data      # data bytes, up to 8

##### END OF FILE #####
```

I would like the fields id, and data to be printed out as hexadecimal numbers. There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do that. Here's an example header sequence obtained using rostopic echo:

```
header: 
  seq: 48533
  stamp: 
    secs: 1402018614
    nsecs: 775459838
  frame_id: ''
time_ms: 132547
time_us: 476
id: 2565877120
msgtype: 0
len: 7
data: [237, 124, 82, 122, 107, 122, 0]
---
```

Hexadecimal for the id and data makes it much easier to comprehend.

Thanks in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172908/ros-msg-format-specification/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic doesn't support custom message formatting.

If you need to print messages to the console in custom format, you should write a custom node.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-06-08**:
I ended up doing this, as I am already writing a ROS node that uses the data for further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easyiest way, I think, is to write a python script with a callback for your particular message and made your transform by yourself !

---

Originally posted by [Jérôme](https://answers.ros.org/users/5102/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/) with karma: 36 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1